# Drill Down Techniques in SSRS 2008 issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report showing location, department and employee name & salary. All of the fields are from same table. I group on location first and then on department. All the groups have group headers. Detail row has employee name & salary.

My report is showing perfect but I want to implement drill down technique. I want to show plus minus symbol for the group. When opened the report should show only location names with plus signs. Then when a user clicks on a plus sign then all departments will show under that location. And when the user clicks on department plus sign then all employee details should show under that department.

I searched google and follow links are

http://forums.asp.net/t/1573640.aspx/1?May+i+use+the+collapse+and+expand+feature+like+tree+menu+in+Report

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1329/drill-down-techniques-in-ssrs-with-the-visibility-property/

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/08/creating-drill-down-report-with-sql.html

I followed their instructions to build expand collapse functionality into my report but failed. Please guide me how to show report location & department wise with expand collapse functionality.

Comment: Why didn't those instructions work? What error do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow these steps

1. In your report, under the Row groups Section , Right Click Details Group - > Add Group - > Parent Group -> Choose Location and include Group Header
2. Now delete the actual Location Column
3. Now again under the Row groups Section, Right Click Location Group - > Add Group - > Child Group -> Choose Department and include Group Header
4. Now delete the actual Department Column.
5. Under the Row groups Section, Right Click Details Group - > Group Properties -> Go to Visibility - > Select Hide for "When the report
   is initially run" and Click the Check box that says "Display can be toggled by this report item and choose "Department1 (Default name for the Department group 
   TextBox, you an change it) as the option"
6. Under the Row groups Section, Right Click Department Group - > Group Properties -> Go to Visibility - > Select Hide for "When the report is initially run" and Click the Check box that says "Display can be toggled by this report item and choose
   "Location1 (Default name for the Location group textBox) as the option"
7. Preview your report and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion....but u said "Now delete the actual Location Column" why should i delete location & department group column because i want to show both the location and department name. please explain what is the logic. thanks

Comment: When you add the Group Header (It is a column by itself). So with the Group Header added you will have 2 columns (Location (Group Header) + Actual Location Column). You can either hide or delete the original Location Column.

Comment: if i delete location & department column then location & department name will not show in my report....am i right?

Comment: No you can still see the department and location columns in your report.Since those two are the Grouping Columns, you will have to click on the +/_ signs to show or hide them. When the report is run initially you see the Location and then as you drilldown you see Department and the detail rows.

Answer (score 2):

Select the textbox that houses the values which you are grouping by. Set the property of that group box's initial Toggle State to True.